# (Basic probability) If you want the largest value in a game, is it better to roll 2 die and sum the results, or to roll 1 die and double the result?

Tags: probability

Say we play a game and want to achieve the highest result possible by either: a) rolling 2 dice and summing the results together or b) rolling 1 dice and doubling the result.

I do not understand why there is a discrepancy in the result of E[2X] and E[X+Y]. Assuming X is the result of the first roll and Y is the result of the second.

Both rolls are independent and identically distributed, so surely E[2X]=E[X+X]=E[X+Y], right?

I get an expectation of 7 in both cases, yet I am told that I need to explain why there is a discrepancy - does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Define "achieve the highest result possible." You didn't use the word "expected" in the problem statement; why are you using it in the solution? (I realize you didn't make the question, but it is ambiguous; maybe that's what you're supposed to investigate.)

Answer (score 3):

As David K noted in a comment, you’re talking about expected values but the question doesn’t mention those. It asks you to achieve the highest result possible, which is $12$ in both cases. What’s the probability of achieving a $12$ in the two cases?

Answer (score 3):

The beauty of combinatorics is that you can either solve a problem in a really complicated manner, or write a simple sentence that is so obvious like the following:

"In (a) you need to get the highest number twice, in (b) you only need to get it once."